# how to change default template auth login in django this is not working?

Tags: django, templates, authentication, default

how to change default template auth login in django this is not working??

urlpatterns = [     path('',views.registration,name='registration'),
path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'),),

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 2):

It is not working because you are passing the template incorrectly.

apps folder should look like this:

`App_name/templates/App_name/login.html`

If your App_name was users, it would be like this:

`path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),`